# Whats the difference between if () {} and if () in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, curly-braces

I've written this code, which is a basic image gallery in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 setInterval("rotateImages()",2000)
 })

function rotateImages() {
     var curPhoto = $("#photoshow div.current");
     var nextPhoto = curPhoto.next();
     if (nextPhoto.length == 0) {
         nextPhoto = $("#photoshow div:first");
     }
     curPhoto.removeClass("current").addClass("previous");
     nextPhoto.css({
         opacity: 0.0
     }).addClass("current").animate({
         opacity: 1.0
     }, 1000‌​, function () {
         curPhoto.removeClass("previous")
     });
}
```

This works, except when I wrap the if statement with {} it doesn't. I just wanted to understand the difference between the two and why it wouldn't work.

Comment: because maybe you're placing the brackets wrongly... do you get any javascript error?

Comment: Where are you putting those curly braces?

Comment: You are welcome. But it is important that you formulate your questions clearer in future (at Stackoverflow and elsewhere), therefor you've got the down votes I think...

Comment: @mustafa: please delete your comment. have updated your code

Comment: sorry about that Naveen thanks for editing it for me :)

Answer (score 1):

multiple lines need {}, otherwise the javascript interpreter doens't know it has more things to run.

try this, it has to work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval("rotateImages()", 2000);
})

function rotateImages() {
    var curPhoto = $("#photoshow div.current")
    var nxtPhoto = curPhoto.next();

    if (nxtPhoto.length == 0) {
        nxtPhoto = $("#photoshow div:first");
        curPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
        nxtPhoto.css({
            opacity: 0.0
        }).addClass('current').animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 1000, function() {
            curPhoto.removeClass('previous');
        });
    }
}
```

**P.S. please also use semi-colons (;) to differentiate lines.**

Comment: thanks for your response, sorry about not using semi-colons, very new to js. The problem i had i figured was to do with me putting the curly braces as your did, as the images do not fade in and out. the brace needed to be put after the line nxtPhoto = $("#photoshow div:first"); once i did it started working. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If an if-statement has only one statement that should be executed conditionally, you can leave away the braces. If more statements must be executed conditionally you have to embrace them as a block of code within braces. My tip: write always a pair of braces, esp. if you are beginning programming!